# Is there any way to disable the Same-origin policy on Google's Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to disable this so I can use a glitch I found to be able to do more homework at one time.

Currently though, what seems to be blocking me is:

`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

This is because the way this glitch works is I connect to the website with http instead of https. But this blocks certain items from loading like assignments to not be allowed to load. I have looked up how to get past this and found a couple of console commands but nothing worked when I tried it. They were also at least a few years old.

If anyone knows how to get around this please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: ^ HEY! That post is 8 years old and everything i found on there didn't work because it was outdated. >:(